# Datetime Picker with Period range jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, calendar

I'm currently using a jQuery Datetime Picker using this:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I have a Start Date and End Date.

It's fine I have a datetime picker calendar but on some parts of my system I need a period range.

For example I have the calendar then beside it is a button:

```
Today, Yesterday, Last week, Last 30 Days, This Month, Last Month
```

Then when the button is clicked, my Start Date and End Date will automatically populate the date according to the period selected. Since it's datetime, time should be `00:00:00` .

How can I do this? Or can you suggest existing plugin or library that has this feature? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just made my own function using [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)